# Using couplers on long Ethernet cable run

Tags: ethernet

I plan to run a Cat6 Ethernet cable from my U-Verse modem to a laptop and a Playstation at the other end of a long house.  The route involves going down into a basement and back up across an attic with the single cable to a 5-port switch (approx 90 ft.), then from the switch on to the laptop and the playstation in two different areas.
The most convenient way to install the cable is using factory patch cords (100', 
50'  2 - 25', 12') involving maybe (4) couplers instead of bulk wire and self-attached connectors (I have no tools).
Will the couplers affect the signal thru the wire enough to be concerned?

There is a Apple AirPort base station also attached to the modem. It provides wireless internet in the original portion of the house.  However, in an added-on section of the house - where the laptop is - the wireless signal does not get thru an original wall.  My reason to install the new cable directly to the laptop.

Comment: Patch cables typically are not rated for in-wall or plenum installation, so you would probably be violating local building codes.

Comment: Appreciate the answers received and the good suggestions.  Have decided to get custom made Cat6 cables - solid core for the long run (80') to the switch in the attic, and plenum cable from switch down chase to basement and inside dropped ceiling space. No patch cables or couplings used.

Answer (score 2):

Connection points are both a potential source of failure and can slightly reduce the distance the signal can travel due to the exposed physical connections and lack of shielding at those points.

I have also seen wall jacks on exterior walls develop corrosion after a few years of bad weather and mediocre insulation. Addressing that issue just involves replacing the ethernet jack in the wall plate, but repairing connection points for in-wall cabling would be much more difficult after the fact.

Do the job right--get a 500ft or 1000ft spool of cable and add the appropriate ends, such as female keystone jacks if you are installing them in wall plates or with raceway and wall-mounted boxes

Comment: Cable going from 1st floor with Modem up to an open attic is exposed inside a closet - not in an insulated wall.  Nearly all of the cable run is in open attic space to the switch (Max 140 F in attic).   From the switch one cable drops down an open chase to the basement, then across the basement ceiling and up thru the floor to the laptop on the first floor.  The  other cable from the switch crosses the attic then drops down thru the ceiling in the room with the Playstation.  None of the cable is inside an insulated wall.  Only 2 couplers will probably be used, and both will be exposed.

Comment: Total cable run around 210 feet complete.

Comment: Yeahbut, unless you use plenum cable, it's a fire risk. and if there is a fire, PVC sleeving puts out toxic fumes.

Answer (score 0):

The overall maximum length for cat 6 cabling is 328 feet.

As long as the couplers are professionally made, (not made in someone's garage) you should be fine, but try to minimize the number of them used. The more of them you use means just more places where something can go wrong.

I my part of the country this cabling is considered "low voltage" cabling and you can run it through all the walls you want without breaking any building codes.

Comment: Regardless of the voltage carried, the flammability of the insulation, e.g. PVC, is a concern.  See #7 of https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-things-you-shouldnt-do-when-running-network-cable/